# Can I call a Pipe from a Pipe in Angular using Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

I'm new to this Angular and Typescript world. I´m currently struggling with the following pipe code: There is already a pipe that checks if `object.struktur.id` should be enabled or not. Now I have to do it with a loop. I literally just copied the code from the other pipe and changed the value to 'i' so that it can iterate.
and I don't know why this is not working.. that's why Im wondering if i can directly call the other pipe from this pipe and give the `object[i].struktur.id` as parameter. is this possible?

```
transform(group: any[]): boolean {
      let probe;
      for(let i=0; i<group.length;i++){
     combineLatest([
        this.iqsService.darfBogenBearbeiten$,
        this.iqsService.enabledStateInbearbeitung$.pipe(
           map(enabledState => enabledState[group[i].struktur.id] != null ? enabledState[group[i].struktur.id] : true),
           distinctUntilChanged()
        ),
        this._erhebungsService.istArchivierteErhebung$
     ]).pipe(
        map(([darfBearbeiten, strukturEnabled, istArchivierteErhebung]) => {
           if (!darfBearbeiten || istArchivierteErhebung) {
              probe= false;
           }
           probe= strukturEnabled;
        })
     );
      }

     return probe;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can call pipe in other pipe, just initiate the pipe and call transform on that

```
let pipe = new YourPipeClass();
let newValue = pipe.transform(value, args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most people would not call a pipe within a pipe but would chain pipes like so:

```
<div>{{ 'HELLO' | lowercase | titlecase }}</div>
```

which gives:

> Hello

It first applies the lowercase pipe which does ... HELLO -> hello

And then applies the titlecase pipe which does ... hello -> Hello

[Docs for chaining pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#transforming-data-with-parameters-and-chained-pipes)